# how to use GmailApp.Sendemail when certain conditions are met?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 5 columns (C2:C, E2:E, F2:F, J2:J, L2:L) in a sheet that i'd like to use when certain conditions are met to send an email
if F2:G <= E2:E, send email with subject like "check out C2:C"
if E2:E >= L2:L AND J2:J <> "", send email with subject like "take a look at C2:C"

I did a bit of searching and found 2 different instances to check for a condition and to send email but not able to put the 2 together to make it work like the above. Below are 2 different scripts, one is commented out just to show what i was working with...

Here is what I have so far:

```
    function Alert() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Display");  
    var ERange = sheet.getRange("E2:E").getValues();
    var FRange = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0;i>ERange.length;i++){
      if(ERange[i]<=FRange[i]){
        results.push("this line met conditions3 "+(i+2)); // +2 because the loop start at zero and first line is the second one (E2)
      }
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail('xx@yy.com', 'subject',     results.join("\n"));
};


//function AlertEmails() {
//  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("EmailDetails"));
//  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
//  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:C3");
//  var data = dataRange.getValues();
//  for (i in data) {
//    var rowData = data[i];
//    var emailAddress = rowData[1];
//    var recipient = rowData[0];
//    var message1 = rowData[2];
//    var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n' + message1;
//    var subject = 'googleSheets test automated script!';
//    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
//  }
//}
```

thanks guys!!

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: hi cooper, sorry i thought it was implied.. the code i have right now isn't doing what i intended it to do, just trying to get guidance on what needs to be fixed in my non-working code. thanks!

Comment: We're not really here to debug your code.  We're here to answer specific questions.  You need to debug your own code.

Comment: got it. thanks for your response. i guess my question is even if the condition is met (      if(ERange[i]<=FRange[i]){) it, and i get an email, the body of the email is empty.

Comment: Can you restate as a question in your question?

Comment: sure thing: https://imgur.com/VrMSUBg

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
function Alert() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Display");  
  var Evalues=sheet.getRange(2,5,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
```

This range format is a little less error prone.  With E2:E you often get nulls between the bottom of data and maxrows.

```
  var Fvalues=sheet.getRange(2,6,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var results=[];
```

In the following line you have i>Evalues.length which is not true so it 
terminated immediately.

```
  for(var i=0;i<Evalues.length;i++){
```

You and I both left out the column indices.  I just added them into the line below:

```
    if(Evalues[i][0]<=Fvalues[i][0]){
      results.push("This line met conditions3 "+(i+2));
    }
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail('xx@yy.com', 'subject',results.join("\n"));
}
```

Comment: hi Cooper, i changed the code like you have, and now get the emails with random lines. However the case i not met but I still get emails, For now, i have about 50 rows but only put 1 row (line 2) where E<=F, however in the email it says line 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10.. and others have met the condition. it seems to be almost completely random as i can't figure out why only certain lines are selected..

Comment: not sure if it matters, but the numbers in column E are a result of a formular/googlefinance

Comment: Try it again I left out the column indices.

Comment: awesome, that worked!! thank you! what is the difference between just [i] and [i][0]. i'll work on adding some other items myself. i may have more questions...

Comment: The first one is the row index and the second one is the column index